# Jsonp getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

In my php I do like this to echo jsonp type 'json data'

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($arr).')';
```

and In my js (angularjs) I do

```
$http.get('http://example.com/app/?callback').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

But I got this error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: it looks like you're requesting json. even though you're returning jsonp. can't be sure though. sorry, haven't used angular for nearly 2 yrs!

Comment: @Elton could you show us the url you are getting the data from... I am not sure if it actually using jsonp...

Comment: Why aren't you using `$http.jsonp()` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to specify `JSON_CALLBACK` as the callback parameter and use `$http.jsonp()` or `$http({method: 'jsonp'})` if you want to use jsonp with `$http`.

You've specified nothing for the callback parameter and are trying to use `$http.get()`.

Give this a whirl:

```
$http.jsonp('http://example.com/app/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
});
```